# Behaviour of GNU sort command (with non-letter ASCII characters, such as dot or semicolon)

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

I want the `sort` command to treat all characters equal.

For example, when I do

```
$ echo -e 'TEST.b\nTESTa\nTESTc' | sort
TESTa
TEST.b
TESTc
```

the dot is ignored.

I would like to get `TEST.b` at the last or first position. However, I cannot find the proper parameter in the manual page.

(my version of `sort` is from the GNU core utilities).

Comment: Which locale do you use?

Comment: I had "LANG=en_US.UTF-8"

Comment: Also found this link: http://superuser.com/questions/226449/why-does-sort-ignore-special-characters-like-the-asterisk

`echo -e 'TEST.b\nTESTa\nTESTc' | sort -V` also works without setting to locale.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Force collation to `C` in order to compare the raw character values.

```
$ echo -e 'TEST.b\nTESTa\nTESTc' | LC_COLLATE=C sort
TEST.b
TESTa
TESTc
```

Comment: I tried LC_ALL=C but it seems to fail in some cases? LC_COLLATE=C worked best!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo -e 'TEST.b\nTESTa\nTESTc' | env -i sort
```