# weird sorting order leading to wrong results

Tags: bash, shell, sorting

`comm` prompts that sorted text is not sorted and `sort` gives wrong results. For example,

```sh
printf 'G.EC\nGE.BO\nGE.DA\n' | sort
```

outputs

```
GE.BOAB
G.ECH
GE.DAG
```

Other example is the output of `ls`,

```
STATIONS_1800
stations.1800.txt
STATIONS.50d
STATIONS.D01
STATIONS.D16
stations.e2008.txt
```

which should be

```
STATIONS_1800
STATIONS.50d
STATIONS.D01
STATIONS.D16
stations.1800.txt
stations.e2008.txt
```

The output of `env | grep 'LC\|LANG'` is

```
LANGUAGE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=en_GB.UTF-8
```

On another machine with the same `LC*` and `LANG*`, the sorting works perfect.

Comment: what is the question? you can pipe `|sort` to get your output sorted

Comment: @Tranbi  the order is not correct, and consequently, commands `sort`, `comm` give wrong results

Comment: And to the guy voting to close, plz read the Q again. This is not a trivial problem. It really brought troubles.

Comment: oh I get it. Have you tried that? https://stackoverflow.com/a/8895544/13525512

Comment: @Tranbi No changes with LANG=C. In fact, I googled before making this Q but failed to find anything related. It's very weird because everything was fine hours ago. The only that may be related is I ran `sudo apt upgrade` on my ubuntu 18.04. But it's hard to verify.

Comment: `ls` should never be used in scripts -- see [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Thus, the only legitimate use of `ls` is interactive, and interactive shell use belongs on [unix.se] or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead of Stack Overflow.

Comment: ...whereas how locales interact with `sort` has many, _many_ duplicates already on this site.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Looks I made an improper title for this Q. Just because `ls` is easy to demonstrate the problem. Of course I don't care so much about the output of list view. The real difficulties are the wrong results of commands like `comm` and `sort` in text processing.

Comment: Noted -- in that case, this should have been closed as a duplicate, instead of as off-topic.

Comment: ...re: candidates for said duplicate flagging: [unix support ignores whitespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923464), [unexpected result from GNU sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691821), [behavior of GNU sort command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982531)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `LC_COLLATE=C`

```sh
$ printf 'G.EC\nGE.BO\nGE.DA\n' | sort
GE.BO
G.EC
GE.DA

$ printf 'G.EC\nGE.BO\nGE.DA\n' | LC_COLLATE=C sort
G.EC
GE.BO
GE.DA
```

Answer (score 1):

From `man sort`:

> ```
>    ***  WARNING  ***  The locale specified by the environment affects sort order.  Set `LC_ALL=C` to get the traditional sort order that uses native byte values.
> ```